# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter' to 'System.Data.DataSet' and doesn't recognize the column name

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I keep getting the following error message:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter' to 'System.Data.DataSet' and doesn't recognize the column name
```

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong. In addition, I kept getting an error saying that it doesn't recognize the column names (for else if statements). This is done in Visal Studio 2017. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2

{

```
public partial class Form1 : Form

{

    public Form1()

    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




        if (comboBox1.Text == "Plan_NAME")
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server2016;Initial Catalog=ProjectRD;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select concat(dbo.[5500].plan_name, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME) as [Plan_NAME], concat(dbo.[5500].ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME) as [Admin_Name], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_EIN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_SPONS_EIN) as [EIN_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_PN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NUM) as [Plan_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].TOT_ACT_RTD_SEP_BENEF_CNT, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ACT_PARTCP_EOY_CNT) as [Number_Participants], concat(concat( (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS1), (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS2))  ,concat((dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS1]), (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS2]) )) as [Address], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_CITY, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_CITY] ))as [City], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_STATE, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_STATE])as [State], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ZIP, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ZIP]) )as [ZipCode], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0))) as [Total_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Net_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) +  (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Total_Liabilities] from dbo.[5500] full join dbo.sch_h on dbo.[5500].ack_id = dbo.sch_h.ack_id full join dbo.SCH_I on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.sch_i.ACK_ID full join dbo.[5500_SF_NEW] on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].ACK_ID where (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME in (Select Sf_Plan_name from Temp_Targets_SF) or dbo.[5500].PLAN_NAME in (Select Plan_Name from Temp_Targets)) and [Plan_NAME] LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "Admin_Name")
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server2016;Initial Catalog=ProjectRD;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select concat(dbo.[5500].plan_name, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME) as [Plan_NAME], concat(dbo.[5500].ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME) as [Admin_Name], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_EIN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_SPONS_EIN) as [EIN_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_PN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NUM) as [Plan_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].TOT_ACT_RTD_SEP_BENEF_CNT, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ACT_PARTCP_EOY_CNT) as [Number_Participants], concat(concat( (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS1), (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS2))  ,concat((dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS1]), (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS2]) )) as [Address], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_CITY, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_CITY] ))as [City], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_STATE, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_STATE])as [State], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ZIP, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ZIP]) )as [ZipCode], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0))) as [Total_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Net_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) +  (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Total_Liabilities] from dbo.[5500] full join dbo.sch_h on dbo.[5500].ack_id = dbo.sch_h.ack_id full join dbo.SCH_I on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.sch_i.ACK_ID full join dbo.[5500_SF_NEW] on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].ACK_ID where (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME in (Select Sf_Plan_name from Temp_Targets_SF) or dbo.[5500].PLAN_NAME in (Select Plan_Name from Temp_Targets))  and [Admin_Name] LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "EIN_Number")
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server2016;Initial Catalog=ProjectRD;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select concat(dbo.[5500].plan_name, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME) as [Plan_NAME], concat(dbo.[5500].ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME) as [Admin_Name], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_EIN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_SPONS_EIN) as [EIN_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_PN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NUM) as [Plan_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].TOT_ACT_RTD_SEP_BENEF_CNT, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ACT_PARTCP_EOY_CNT) as [Number_Participants], concat(concat( (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS1), (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS2))  ,concat((dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS1]), (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS2]) )) as [Address], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_CITY, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_CITY] ))as [City], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_STATE, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_STATE])as [State], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ZIP, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ZIP]) )as [ZipCode], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0))) as [Total_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Net_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) +  (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Total_Liabilities] from dbo.[5500] full join dbo.sch_h on dbo.[5500].ack_id = dbo.sch_h.ack_id full join dbo.SCH_I on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.sch_i.ACK_ID full join dbo.[5500_SF_NEW] on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].ACK_ID where (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME in (Select Sf_Plan_name from Temp_Targets_SF) or dbo.[5500].PLAN_NAME in (Select Plan_Name from Temp_Targets))  and [EIN_Number] LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

        }
                    else if (comboBox1.Text == "Number_Participants")
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server2016;Initial Catalog=ProjectRD;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select concat(dbo.[5500].plan_name, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME) as [Plan_NAME], concat(dbo.[5500].ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME) as [Admin_Name], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_EIN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_SPONS_EIN) as [EIN_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_PN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NUM) as [Plan_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].TOT_ACT_RTD_SEP_BENEF_CNT, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ACT_PARTCP_EOY_CNT) as [Number_Participants], concat(concat( (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS1), (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS2))  ,concat((dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS1]), (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS2]) )) as [Address], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_CITY, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_CITY] ))as [City], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_STATE, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_STATE])as [State], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ZIP, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ZIP]) )as [ZipCode], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0))) as [Total_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Net_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) +  (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Total_Liabilities] from dbo.[5500] full join dbo.sch_h on dbo.[5500].ack_id = dbo.sch_h.ack_id full join dbo.SCH_I on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.sch_i.ACK_ID full join dbo.[5500_SF_NEW] on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].ACK_ID where (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME in (Select Sf_Plan_name from Temp_Targets_SF) or dbo.[5500].PLAN_NAME in (Select Plan_Name from Temp_Targets))  and ([Number_Participants] between '%" + textBox3.Text + "%' and '%" + textBox2.Text + "%')", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "City")
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server2016;Initial Catalog=ProjectRD;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select concat(dbo.[5500].plan_name, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME) as [Plan_NAME], concat(dbo.[5500].ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME) as [Admin_Name], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_EIN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_SPONS_EIN) as [EIN_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_PN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NUM) as [Plan_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].TOT_ACT_RTD_SEP_BENEF_CNT, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ACT_PARTCP_EOY_CNT) as [Number_Participants], concat(concat( (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS1), (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS2))  ,concat((dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS1]), (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS2]) )) as [Address], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_CITY, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_CITY] ))as [City], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_STATE, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_STATE])as [State], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ZIP, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ZIP]) )as [ZipCode], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0))) as [Total_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Net_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) +  (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Total_Liabilities] from dbo.[5500] full join dbo.sch_h on dbo.[5500].ack_id = dbo.sch_h.ack_id full join dbo.SCH_I on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.sch_i.ACK_ID full join dbo.[5500_SF_NEW] on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].ACK_ID where (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME in (Select Sf_Plan_name from Temp_Targets_SF) or dbo.[5500].PLAN_NAME in (Select Plan_Name from Temp_Targets))  and [City] LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "State")
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server2016;Initial Catalog=ProjectRD;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select concat(dbo.[5500].plan_name, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME) as [Plan_NAME], concat(dbo.[5500].ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME) as [Admin_Name], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_EIN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_SPONS_EIN) as [EIN_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_PN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NUM) as [Plan_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].TOT_ACT_RTD_SEP_BENEF_CNT, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ACT_PARTCP_EOY_CNT) as [Number_Participants], concat(concat( (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS1), (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS2))  ,concat((dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS1]), (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS2]) )) as [Address], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_CITY, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_CITY] ))as [City], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_STATE, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_STATE])as [State], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ZIP, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ZIP]) )as [ZipCode], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0))) as [Total_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Net_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) +  (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Total_Liabilities] from dbo.[5500] full join dbo.sch_h on dbo.[5500].ack_id = dbo.sch_h.ack_id full join dbo.SCH_I on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.sch_i.ACK_ID full join dbo.[5500_SF_NEW] on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].ACK_ID where (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME in (Select Sf_Plan_name from Temp_Targets_SF) or dbo.[5500].PLAN_NAME in (Select Plan_Name from Temp_Targets))  and [State] LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "ZipCode")
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server2016;Initial Catalog=ProjectRD;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select concat(dbo.[5500].plan_name, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME) as [Plan_NAME], concat(dbo.[5500].ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME) as [Admin_Name], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_EIN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_SPONS_EIN) as [EIN_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_PN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NUM) as [Plan_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].TOT_ACT_RTD_SEP_BENEF_CNT, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ACT_PARTCP_EOY_CNT) as [Number_Participants], concat(concat( (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS1), (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS2))  ,concat((dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS1]), (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS2]) )) as [Address], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_CITY, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_CITY] ))as [City], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_STATE, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_STATE])as [State], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ZIP, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ZIP]) )as [ZipCode], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0))) as [Total_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Net_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) +  (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Total_Liabilities] from dbo.[5500] full join dbo.sch_h on dbo.[5500].ack_id = dbo.sch_h.ack_id full join dbo.SCH_I on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.sch_i.ACK_ID full join dbo.[5500_SF_NEW] on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].ACK_ID where (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME in (Select Sf_Plan_name from Temp_Targets_SF) or dbo.[5500].PLAN_NAME in (Select Plan_Name from Temp_Targets))  and [ZipCode] LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "Total_Assets")
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server2016;Initial Catalog=ProjectRD;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select concat(dbo.[5500].plan_name, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME) as [Plan_NAME], concat(dbo.[5500].ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME) as [Admin_Name], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_EIN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_SPONS_EIN) as [EIN_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_PN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NUM) as [Plan_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].TOT_ACT_RTD_SEP_BENEF_CNT, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ACT_PARTCP_EOY_CNT) as [Number_Participants], concat(concat( (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS1), (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS2))  ,concat((dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS1]), (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS2]) )) as [Address], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_CITY, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_CITY] ))as [City], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_STATE, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_STATE])as [State], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ZIP, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ZIP]) )as [ZipCode], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0))) as [Total_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Net_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) +  (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Total_Liabilities] from dbo.[5500] full join dbo.sch_h on dbo.[5500].ack_id = dbo.sch_h.ack_id full join dbo.SCH_I on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.sch_i.ACK_ID full join dbo.[5500_SF_NEW] on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].ACK_ID where (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME in (Select Sf_Plan_name from Temp_Targets_SF) or dbo.[5500].PLAN_NAME in (Select Plan_Name from Temp_Targets))  and ([Total_Assets] between '%" + textBox3.Text + "%' and '%" + textBox2.Text + "%')", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

        }
        else if (comboBox1.Text == "Net_Assets")
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server2016;Initial Catalog=ProjectRD;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select concat(dbo.[5500].plan_name, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME) as [Plan_NAME], concat(dbo.[5500].ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME) as [Admin_Name], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_EIN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_SPONS_EIN) as [EIN_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_PN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NUM) as [Plan_Number], concat(dbo.[5500].TOT_ACT_RTD_SEP_BENEF_CNT, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ACT_PARTCP_EOY_CNT) as [Number_Participants], concat(concat( (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS1), (dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS2))  ,concat((dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS1]), (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS2]) )) as [Address], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_CITY, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_CITY] ))as [City], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_STATE, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_STATE])as [State], concat(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ZIP, (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ZIP]) )as [ZipCode], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0))) as [Total_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Net_Assets], ((isNull(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) + (isNull(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0)) +  (isNull(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT,0)) ) as [Total_Liabilities] from dbo.[5500] full join dbo.sch_h on dbo.[5500].ack_id = dbo.sch_h.ack_id full join dbo.SCH_I on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.sch_i.ACK_ID full join dbo.[5500_SF_NEW] on dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].ACK_ID where (dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME in (Select Sf_Plan_name from Temp_Targets_SF) or dbo.[5500].PLAN_NAME in (Select Plan_Name from Temp_Targets))  and ([Net_Assets] between '%" + textBox3.Text + "%' and '%" + textBox2.Text + "%')", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;


        }
    }
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner more concise code would probably have gotten a quicker answer.

One issue I can see is for the 3 situations where you're adding a where term based on a number (Number_Participants, Total_Assets, Net_Assets), you include `'%" ... "%'` either side which is not applicable when using `BETWEEN`.  I rewrote your basic code below to condense it, apply some common SQL style and hopefully make it more readable, but skipped parameterization for now.

See if that solves your problem.

```
string selectTerm = @"SELECT CONCAT(dbo.[5500].plan_name, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME) [Plan_NAME]
        , CONCAT(dbo.[5500].ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_ADMIN_CARE_OF_NAME) [Admin_Name]
        , CONCAT(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_EIN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_SPONS_EIN) [EIN_Number]
        , CONCAT(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_PN, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NUM) [Plan_Number]
        , CONCAT(dbo.[5500].TOT_ACT_RTD_SEP_BENEF_CNT, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ACT_PARTCP_EOY_CNT) [Number_Participants]
        , CONCAT(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS1, dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ADDRESS2, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS1], dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ADDRESS2]) [Address]
        , CONCAT(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_CITY, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_CITY]) [City]
        , CONCAT(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_STATE, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_STATE]) [State]
        , CONCAT(dbo.[5500].SPONS_DFE_MAIL_US_ZIP, dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].[SF_SPONS_US_ZIP]) [ZipCode]
        , (ISNULL(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0) + ISNULL(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0) + ISNULL(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0)) [Total_Assets]
        , (ISNULL(dbo.SCH_H.NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0) + ISNULL(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT, 0) + ISNULL(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT,0)) [Net_Assets]
        , (ISNULL(dbo.SCH_H.TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0) + ISNULL(dbo.SCH_I.SMALL_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT, 0) +  ISNULL(dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_TOT_LIABILITIES_EOY_AMT,0)) [Total_Liabilities]
     FROM dbo.[5500] 
        FULL JOIN dbo.sch_h ON dbo.[5500].ack_id = dbo.sch_h.ack_id
        FULL JOIN dbo.SCH_I ON dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.sch_i.ACK_ID
        FULL JOIN dbo.[5500_SF_NEW] ON dbo.[5500].ACK_ID = dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].ACK_ID
     WHERE dbo.[5500_SF_NEW].SF_PLAN_NAME IN (SELECT Sf_Plan_name FROM Temp_Targets_SF)
        OR dbo.[5500].PLAN_NAME IN (SELECT Plan_Name FROM Temp_Targets)";

string whereTerm;

if (comboBox1.Text == "Plan_NAME") whereTerm = " AND [Plan_NAME] LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%';";
else if (comboBox1.Text == "Admin_Name") whereTerm = " AND [Admin_Name] LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%';";
else if (comboBox1.Text == "EIN_Number") whereTerm = " AND [EIN_Number] LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%';";
else if (comboBox1.Text == "Number_Participants") whereTerm = " AND [Number_Participants] BETWEEN " + textBox3.Text + " AND " + textBox2.Text + ";";
else if (comboBox1.Text == "City") whereTerm = " AND [City] LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%';";
else if (comboBox1.Text == "State") whereTerm = " AND [State] LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%';";
else if (comboBox1.Text == "ZipCode") whereTerm = "AND [ZipCode] LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%';";
else if (comboBox1.Text == "Total_Assets") whereTerm = " AND [Total_Assets] BETWEEN " + textBox3.Text + " AND " + textBox2.Text + ";";
else if (comboBox1.Text == "Net_Assets") whereTerm = " AND [Net_Assets] BETWEEN " + textBox3.Text + " AND " + textBox2.Text + ";";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server2016;Initial Catalog=ProjectRD;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(selectTerm + whereTerm, con);
DataTable data = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(data);
dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```